# Jquery datatable integration error?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am integrating jquery datatable to my project. When call is made to service, some how following error is error thrown

**cannot read property 'assorting' of undefined**

Here is the code

Timeline

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

```
<body>

<script>

$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "URL",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
    console.log(aoData);
      oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
        "dataType": 'json',
        "type": "POST",
        "url": sSource,
        "data": aoData,
        "success": fnCallback
      } );
    }
  } );
} );

</script>

<div id="dvContent">
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  id="example">

 </table>
</div>

</body>
```

Here is the Sample out put of the server

{"some":"yyy",
"open":null,
"program":1,
"more":"must",
"comment":000
}

Comment: where in your code you are trying to read `assorting`..paste that code..

Comment: no I don't want asorting. I haven't done any coding for that. By default this error is comming

Comment: its not what u want..its where u've used it?? so that we can see whats wrong..

Comment: I am not at all using that property.

Comment: What other scripts are you including aside from jquery?

Comment: Edit your question with those details, don't post them in your comment.

Comment: Yes _what_ is?  And I asked for the scripts aside from jquery you were using, if any.

Comment: @Daedalus, yes I am using http://datatables.net plugin. No other script are used.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your table needs a THEAD section and a TBODY section:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  id="example">
   <thead><tr><th>First Column</th><th>Second Column etc.</th></tr></thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: it's also important that your THEAD not be *empty* as dataTable requires you to specify the number of columns of the expected data as specified by `<tr><th></th></tr>`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the point by @bumptious above, it's important to note that the THEAD section cannot be blank; dataTables requires the `<tr><th>column1</th></tr>` content as placeholder within the table.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also occur when you use "order" clause and refer to non-existing field/column.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

Table should have  &  section.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your table's number of data columns td is equal to header columns th.