# jQuery Datatables: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm am new in jQuery, so sorry if my question is too simple.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$("#send-one").html('done. ');

var tableProgress= $("<table id='table-progress'><tr><td></td></tr></table>");

$("#send-one").empty().append(tableProgress);

tableProgress.dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false
});
```

All this occurs inside [jQuery ui Dialog Box](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

It does not work, I think it's because [.dataTable() pluggin](http://www.datatables.net/) can't find the table so I am trying to use [jQuery $.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

The error is this

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined

What I need is: use .datatable pluggin in a table that is inserted in `$("#send-one").html('done. ' + tableProgress)` but, using .datatable() directly may not be synchronous to the insertion.

I also tried:

```
$("#send-one").html('done. ' + tableProgress);
$('#table-progress').dataTable();
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you're using Deferred objects, which is pretty much required for this. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you want to achieve, instead of letting us guess based on your not-working code.

Comment: sorry. I made an edit.

Comment: Nothing yet.. please, help!

Comment: I had such issue when used outdated version of Datatable. Upgrading to 1.10.5 solved my problem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This other stack overflow question had a much clearer answer, that it must have a `<thead>` and a `<tbody>` to work:
[Jquery datatable integration error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319979/jquery-datatable-integration-error#log-in)

Your's is missing both.

Comment: Just a note: You dont need a <tbody> and <thead> in case you supply columns via init script

Answer (score 8):

I did this and it works. apparently some problem with aoSorting of datatables. I don't know why.

```
$("#send-one").html('done. ');

var tableProgress= $("<table id='table-progress'><tr><th></th></tr><tr><td></td></tr></table>");

$("#send-one").empty().append(tableProgress);

tableProgress.dataTable( {
    "aoColumns": [
          null
        ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dataTable columnFilter plugin, this one solved my problem.

Just change _fnColumnIndex like this:

```
function _fnColumnIndex(iColumnIndex) {
        return iColumnIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not call any asynchronous function (such as some AJAX calls) so the `$.when` function doesn't make sense here.

As you use functions which will be called after the last one has completed the following code should work.

```
var tableProgress;
tableProgress = "<table id='table-progress'><tr><td></td></tr></table>";
$("#send-one").html('done. ' + tableProgress);
$('#table-progress').dataTable();
```

Comment: #table-progress does not exist when document ready... it starts to exist after a file upload...

Comment: I did it at first.. but it does not work. So I think about $.when... what do I suppose to test?

Answer (score 0):

```
function someAction() {
            var tableProgress;
            tableProgress = $("<table id='table-progress'><tr><td></td></tr></table>");
            $("#send-one").append(tableProgress);
            tableProgress.dataTable();                                       
}
```

adds the table to `#send-one`, on document ready, and then calls the dataTable on it. No sense using the id since you can just have it already in an jQuery object.

Comment: It has document ready, but #table-progress does not exists at the beginning.. only after some user interaction..

Comment: yea updated my answer. You could just put the table code into a jQuery object, and add it to the document and then call dataTable on it.

Comment: it does not work.. =( Uncaught TypeError: Object <table id='table-progress'>........</table> has no method 'dataTable'

Comment: then your dataTable plugin isnt loaded yet, you are executing that code before it has time to load.

Comment: it is loaded. I have a table that is cell is clickable and then open an dialog box (from jquery ui) Than I do what is above...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you load the plugin .js file correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/CdRa5/6/

```
var tableProgress = $('<table id="table-progress"><thead><tr><th>heading</th><th>heading</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr><tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr></tbody></table>');
$("#send-one").empty().append(tableProgress);
tableProgress.dataTable();
```

Comment: Thank you matty, but did not work... still same error.. it is inside a dialog box of jquery ui... could this be the error?

Comment: try changing third line to select the DOM node again: $('#table-progress').dataTable(); And don't forget about correct table structure, this plugin doesn't work on table without headings.